# Freeze a shortcode in place?

Tags: shortcode

Is there a way to "freeze" a shortcode in place so non-Administrators can't edit it?

Let's say I have a page like this:

[shortcode]

Text of the page

[other shortcode]

---

Is there a way that non-Administrators would see the page as the following:

*[shortcode]*

Text of the page

*[other shortcode]*

Where the italicized shortcodes are untouchable/uneditable?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to do it like that, but you can hook into the filter `the_content` and prepend the output of `do_shortcode( 'before_content_shortcode' )` to the actual content and append the the output of `do_shortcode( 'after_content_shortcode' )`.

```
function so_modify_the_content( $content ) {
    $prependContent = do_shortcode( 'pre_content_shortcode' );
    $appendContent  = do_shortcode( 'post_content_shortcode' );

    $content        = $prependContent . $content . $appendContent;

    return $content; 
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'so_modify_the_content' );
```

Comment: can you explain in further detail? i'm a bit new to hooks and filters :)

Comment: Please, see my edit. The function runs shortcodes, stores their results and then wraps content in those results, so to say. And it's triggered when the content is being showed on the page to the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for user capability (aka non-admins) and remove shortcode you don't want to be formatted:

...in functions.php

```
$cuser = wp_get_current_user();
if (!isset($cuser->allcaps['administrator']) || !$cuser->allcaps['administrator']) {
    remove_shortcode('your_shortcode_tag_name');
}
```

You can also remove all shortcodes using [remove_all_shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_shortcodes) function.

Comment: that's amazing! i wouldn't need to remove shortcodes, just don't want other users to touch them. i'll need to try this out!

Comment: can i make this a general "hide all shortcodes" thing, or do i have to specify by specific shortcode?

Comment: this doesn't hide shortcodes in the editor, it removes the shortcode handler that renders the shortcode when content is viewed on the front end.

Comment: If I understand correctly OP wanted to still have actual string "[shortcode]" visible inside the content.

Comment: @Jamie you can wrap the whole thing in a function and/or add all shortcode names to some array and loop the `remove_shortcode` part.